# SQL Procedure use

Tags: sql

Parameters are displaying an error and I typed them as follows:

```
 where createdon between @startdate and @enddate
        and pt.[state] in @([state])
        and pt.carrier in (@Carrier)
        and pt.LineOfBusiness IN (@LOB)
```

All these are added for the where clause

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: "displaying an error" - please specify what that error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are attempting to write:

```
 where createdon between @startdate and @enddate and
       pt.[state] in (@state) and
       pt.carrier in (@Carrier) and
       pt.LineOfBusiness in (@LOB)
```

This does not do what you want.  Presumably you intend something like this:

```
 where createdon >= @startdate and createdon < @enddate + interval 1 day  and
       pt.[state] = @state and
       pt.carrier = @Carrier and
       pt.LineOfBusiness = @LOB
```

Two notes:

- `in` with a variable is exactly equivalent to `=`.  So use that.
- `between` ignores time components.  Presumably, `createdon` has a time component, so this captures what is most likely your intended logic.

If you want to use `in`, then you cannot use a simple variable.  Depending on the database, there may be way to implement a solution.